# Unable to save shopt globstar output to variable

Tags: bash, shopt

I'm trying to save the current status of `shopt globstar` to a variable so I can change it if needed then set it back as to not leave the user's environment altered.

I have tried storing the command output multiple ways such as `var=$(command)` and `` var=`command` `` but when I test with
`echo $var` it always reads the state as "off" even though it's not.

```
gstar=$( shopt globstar )
echo "$gstar"
```

I'm hoping to use echo to test the current state against manually running `shopt globstar` but they do not match.

This basic variable store is working fine with `whoami` command.

Comment: If you are writing a bash script it cannot normally modify the caller's environment anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running your script directly (`./script.sh`) or sourcing it (`. script.sh` or `source script.sh`)?

1. If you're running it directly it'll have its own environment and you don't have to worry about preserving the user's settings. Scripts get a copy of the user's environment and changes only affect the copy, not the original. Just set the option however you like at the top of your script.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   shopt -s globstar
   foo **/bar
   ```
2. If it's being sourced it's a lot easier to just wrap the relevant parts of the script in a subshell so they run in an isolated environment.

   ```
   (
       shopt -s globstar
       foo **/bar
   )
   baz
   ```

I suspect it's case 1 since you say it always starts out `off`.

Comment: Yes, the script is called directly via ./script.sh
So in this case sounds like #1 is the case and I need not worry about reading the state.
This is great info I didn't know prior (just dipping my toes into scripting)

I really appreciate the help on this!

Answer (score 2):

To save the shopt value:

```
if shopt -q globstar
then
  # the option is enabled
  saved_globstar=-s
else
  # the option is disabled
  saved_globstar=-u
fi
```

Now you can change your globstar value. If you later want to restore it to the previous state, do a

```
shopt $saved_globstar globstar
```